# How to connect an app to a Bluetooth headset

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to connect my application to a bluetooth headset but I get errors for `mProfileListener`. I am not sure where and how to declare `mProfileListener`.
 Here is my code:

```
// Get the default adapter
   BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


// Establish connection to the proxy.
   mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(this, mProfileListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);

   private BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener mProfileListener = new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {
       public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {
           if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
               mBluetoothHeadset = (BluetoothHeadset) proxy;
               Log.d("TAGP","BLuetooth Headset: "+mBluetoothHeadset);
               Log.d("TAGP ","Proxy: "+proxy);
           }
       }
       public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) {
           if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
               mBluetoothHeadset = null;
           }
       }
   };

   // ... call functions on mBluetoothHeadset

   // Close proxy connection after use.
   mBluetoothAdapter.closeProfileProxy(mBluetoothHeadset);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may declare the mProfileListener instance in the class scope as follows:

```
private BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener mProfileListener;
```

then within your "connected" method of Bluetooth stack, you may inititalize this mProfileListener instance as like your code.